# Java AST traversal

Tags: java, antlr, traversal, abstract-syntax-tree

so, I'm currently working on a DSL implementation by using ANTLR with Java. By so far, I've created my own AST hierarchy based on the ANTLR grammar. Why? Because unfortunately, ANTLR v4 doesn't support output=AST.

Anyway, the hierarchy can be simplified as the following:

```
Expressions
-> BinaryExpressions(Expressions, Expressions)
    -> Multiplication(Expression, Expression)
    -> Addition(Expression, Expression)
    -> Greater_Equal(Expression, Expression)
    -> Less_Equal(Expression, Expression)
```

and the list goes on. Anyway, given this, I produce a quite well organised hierarchy so far. So for example 3 + (2 * 3) would produce something like:

```
Addition(Integer(3), Multiplication(Integer(2), Integer(3))
```

where the class of the object is addition.

Anyway, given this, how can I traverse over this hierarchy? The example above is just a quick overview of the overall complexity, but how can I by using recursive functions iterate over this? Because for instance, defining for (ASTNode node : someNode) doesn't work because the object of ASTNode (top level class - the mother of all classes) cannot be iterated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do, really.

For instance, if you want to evaluate the formula you just parsed, you could endow each AST node with a `eval()` method, by defining an interface:

```
public interface Evaluable {
    Something eval();
}
```

at this point, you can define the operation for all nodes, like:

```
public class Integer implements Evaluable {
    @Override
    public Something eval() {
        return value;
    }

    private final Something value;
}
```

and then:

```
public class Multiplication implements Evaluable {
    @Override
    public Something eval() {
        return left.eval().product(right.eval());
    }

    private final Expression left;
    private final Expression right;
}
```

and so on.

At this point, you call `.eval()` on the root node and the call will be recursively propagated, and the result propagated back to the top.

This is just a quick solution. More refined (and complicated) ones rely on a double indirection pattern, in which the eval method is passed an `Evaluator`, which defines an overloaded `eval` method for each type and encapsulates the operations, thus separating them from the AST nodes.